# Android Sqlite db creation / location issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with a basic [example](http://programmingknowledgeblog.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-1.html) of Android Sqlite.

**Issue 1:**
As per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8TaTgr4uKMIt), it runs perfectly without any errors but - when I take Android Device Monitor I cannot locate my project with full name -- all the folders under `data > data` are named as `abc` (which is the **package extension only!**)

[image]

As per the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8TaTgr4uKM), why is my ADM not showing the full package name such `as abc.mycom.com.sqliteapp` or how can I locate my db (students.db)?

**Issue 2:**
In order to solve this, when I try a specific path using

```
public  static final String DATABASE_NAME= "/mnt/sdcard/student.db";
```

I get '*Unfortunately the app has stopped*' error.

I have added the following permission:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: It's already there in the post. Issue1 - I cannot locate my db in ADM  Issue 2. I get 'Unfortunately the app has stopped' error

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful about android permissions.In android 6.0 and above , there are some specific permissions that cannot be granted only by using manifest permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE won't work on android 6.0 and above if the user doesn't active it by going to "Application Info" -> "Permissions".And for get the app location "to store your data base" you don't need write external storage permission.Here is my code for get app data path:

```java
    public static String getDataDir(Context context) throws Exception {
        return context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0)
                .applicationInfo.dataDir;
          }
```

However , please explain about your debugging error (LogCat).